# How to display javascript from ajax response in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

I am designed one web application in which I want to show the plot which will be received by ajax response.This plot is written in javascript.I want to put this plot as the HTML div.
Below is my HTML code,

```
{%load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<head>
<script src=" {% static 'jquery-1.12.4.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</html>
<div id="plot"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/visualization/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    //data: JSON.stringify(finalJson),
    //dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
                console.log("!!!Reponse!!!")
                console.log(reponse)
                document.getElementById("plot").innerHTML = response
        }
});
}
</script>
```

Below is javascript received for plot:

```
<style>

</style>

<div id="fig_el150211404154248054569977043312"></div>
<script>
function mpld3_load_lib(url, callback){
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = url;
  s.async = true;
  s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = callback;
  s.onerror = function(){console.warn("failed to load library " + url);};
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}

if(typeof(mpld3) !== "undefined" && mpld3._mpld3IsLoaded){
   // already loaded: just create the figure
   !function(mpld3){

       mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el150211404154248054569977043312", {"axes": [{"xlim": [-1.1078409018075122, 1.1078409018075119], "yscale": "linear", "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "texts": [{"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP1", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296730768"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP2", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296731792"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP3", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296732368"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP4", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296732944"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP5", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296778640"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP6", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296779280"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP7", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296779920"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP8", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296780560"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP9", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296781200"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP10", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296781840"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP11", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296729872"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP12", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296819536"}], "zoomable": true, "images": [], "xdomain": [-1.1078409018075122, 1.1078409018075119], "ylim": [-1.6605224223390853, 1.6605224223390858], "paths": [], "sharey": [], "sharex": [], "axesbgalpha": null, "axes": [{"scale": "linear", "tickformat": null, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true, "fontsize": 10.0, "position": "bottom", "nticks": 11, "tickvalues": null}, {"scale": "linear", "tickformat": null, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true, "fontsize": 10.0, "position": "left", "nticks": 9, "tickvalues": null}], "lines": [], "markers": [], "id": "el15021140415331251472", "ydomain": [-1.6605224223390853, 1.6605224223390858], "collections": [{"paths": [[[[0.0, -0.5], [0.13260155, -0.5], [0.25978993539242673, -0.44731684579412084], [0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738], [0.44731684579412084, -0.25978993539242673], [0.5, -0.13260155], [0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.13260155], [0.44731684579412084, 0.25978993539242673], [0.3535533905932738, 0.3535533905932738], [0.25978993539242673, 0.44731684579412084], [0.13260155, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [-0.13260155, 0.5], [-0.25978993539242673, 0.44731684579412084], [-0.3535533905932738, 0.3535533905932738], [-0.44731684579412084, 0.25978993539242673], [-0.5, 0.13260155], [-0.5, 0.0], [-0.5, -0.13260155], [-0.44731684579412084, -0.25978993539242673], [-0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738], [-0.25978993539242673, -0.44731684579412084], [-0.13260155, -0.5], [0.0, -0.5]], ["M", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Z"]]], "edgecolors": ["#440154", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#35B778", "#FDE724", "#440154", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#30678D"], "edgewidths": [1.0], "offsets": "data01", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330713744", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#440154", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#35B778", "#FDE724", "#440154", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#30678D"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data02", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330714960", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data03", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330715920", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data04", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330717008", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data05", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415296729616", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}], "xscale": "linear", "bbox": [0.125, 0.10999999999999999, 0.77500000000000002, 0.77000000000000002]}], "height": 480.0, "width": 640.0, "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"enabled": false, "button": true, "type": "zoom"}, {"enabled": false, "button": true, "type": "boxzoom"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:1"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330714960"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:2"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330715920"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:3"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330717008"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:4"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415296729616"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": null, "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330713744"}], "data": {"data04": [[0.9272438562460922, 0.3299853259969276]], "data05": [[0.09099394357686544, -0.8983310538531637]], "data02": [[0.7580185107925308, 0.7591373404478057]], "data03": [[-0.8850288966385835, 1.4182636012752556]], "data01": [[-1.0, 1.5], [0.0, 1.5], [1.0, 1.5], [-1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5], [-1.0, -0.5], [0.0, -0.5], [1.0, -0.5], [-1.0, -1.5], [0.0, -1.5], [1.0, -1.5]]}, "id": "el15021140415424805456"});
   }(mpld3);
}else if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd){
   // require.js is available: use it to load d3/mpld3
   require.config({paths: {d3: "https://mpld3.github.io/js/d3.v3.min"}});
   require(["d3"], function(d3){
      window.d3 = d3;
      mpld3_load_lib("https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.3.js", function(){

         mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el150211404154248054569977043312", {"axes": [{"xlim": [-1.1078409018075122, 1.1078409018075119], "yscale": "linear", "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "texts": [{"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP1", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296730768"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP2", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296731792"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP3", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296732368"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP4", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296732944"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP5", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296778640"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP6", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296779280"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP7", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296779920"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP8", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296780560"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP9", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296781200"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP10", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296781840"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP11", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296729872"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP12", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296819536"}], "zoomable": true, "images": [], "xdomain": [-1.1078409018075122, 1.1078409018075119], "ylim": [-1.6605224223390853, 1.6605224223390858], "paths": [], "sharey": [], "sharex": [], "axesbgalpha": null, "axes": [{"scale": "linear", "tickformat": null, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true, "fontsize": 10.0, "position": "bottom", "nticks": 11, "tickvalues": null}, {"scale": "linear", "tickformat": null, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true, "fontsize": 10.0, "position": "left", "nticks": 9, "tickvalues": null}], "lines": [], "markers": [], "id": "el15021140415331251472", "ydomain": [-1.6605224223390853, 1.6605224223390858], "collections": [{"paths": [[[[0.0, -0.5], [0.13260155, -0.5], [0.25978993539242673, -0.44731684579412084], [0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738], [0.44731684579412084, -0.25978993539242673], [0.5, -0.13260155], [0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.13260155], [0.44731684579412084, 0.25978993539242673], [0.3535533905932738, 0.3535533905932738], [0.25978993539242673, 0.44731684579412084], [0.13260155, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [-0.13260155, 0.5], [-0.25978993539242673, 0.44731684579412084], [-0.3535533905932738, 0.3535533905932738], [-0.44731684579412084, 0.25978993539242673], [-0.5, 0.13260155], [-0.5, 0.0], [-0.5, -0.13260155], [-0.44731684579412084, -0.25978993539242673], [-0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738], [-0.25978993539242673, -0.44731684579412084], [-0.13260155, -0.5], [0.0, -0.5]], ["M", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Z"]]], "edgecolors": ["#440154", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#35B778", "#FDE724", "#440154", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#30678D"], "edgewidths": [1.0], "offsets": "data01", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330713744", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#440154", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#35B778", "#FDE724", "#440154", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#30678D"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data02", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330714960", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data03", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330715920", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data04", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330717008", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data05", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415296729616", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}], "xscale": "linear", "bbox": [0.125, 0.10999999999999999, 0.77500000000000002, 0.77000000000000002]}], "height": 480.0, "width": 640.0, "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"enabled": false, "button": true, "type": "zoom"}, {"enabled": false, "button": true, "type": "boxzoom"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:1"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330714960"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:2"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330715920"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:3"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330717008"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:4"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415296729616"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": null, "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330713744"}], "data": {"data04": [[0.9272438562460922, 0.3299853259969276]], "data05": [[0.09099394357686544, -0.8983310538531637]], "data02": [[0.7580185107925308, 0.7591373404478057]], "data03": [[-0.8850288966385835, 1.4182636012752556]], "data01": [[-1.0, 1.5], [0.0, 1.5], [1.0, 1.5], [-1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5], [-1.0, -0.5], [0.0, -0.5], [1.0, -0.5], [-1.0, -1.5], [0.0, -1.5], [1.0, -1.5]]}, "id": "el15021140415424805456"});
      });
    });
}else{
    // require.js not available: dynamically load d3 & mpld3
    mpld3_load_lib("https://mpld3.github.io/js/d3.v3.min.js", function(){
         mpld3_load_lib("https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.3.js", function(){

                 mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el150211404154248054569977043312", {"axes": [{"xlim": [-1.1078409018075122, 1.1078409018075119], "yscale": "linear", "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "texts": [{"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP1", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296730768"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP2", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296731792"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP3", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, 1.7], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296732368"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP4", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296732944"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP5", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296778640"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP6", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, 0.69999999999999996], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296779280"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP7", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296779920"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP8", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296780560"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP9", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, -0.29999999999999999], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296781200"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP10", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [-1.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296781840"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP11", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [0.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296729872"}, {"v_baseline": "auto", "h_anchor": "start", "color": "#000000", "text": "RP12", "coordinates": "data", "zorder": 3, "alpha": 1, "fontsize": 8.0, "position": [1.0, -1.3], "rotation": -0.0, "id": "el15021140415296819536"}], "zoomable": true, "images": [], "xdomain": [-1.1078409018075122, 1.1078409018075119], "ylim": [-1.6605224223390853, 1.6605224223390858], "paths": [], "sharey": [], "sharex": [], "axesbgalpha": null, "axes": [{"scale": "linear", "tickformat": null, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true, "fontsize": 10.0, "position": "bottom", "nticks": 11, "tickvalues": null}, {"scale": "linear", "tickformat": null, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true, "fontsize": 10.0, "position": "left", "nticks": 9, "tickvalues": null}], "lines": [], "markers": [], "id": "el15021140415331251472", "ydomain": [-1.6605224223390853, 1.6605224223390858], "collections": [{"paths": [[[[0.0, -0.5], [0.13260155, -0.5], [0.25978993539242673, -0.44731684579412084], [0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738], [0.44731684579412084, -0.25978993539242673], [0.5, -0.13260155], [0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.13260155], [0.44731684579412084, 0.25978993539242673], [0.3535533905932738, 0.3535533905932738], [0.25978993539242673, 0.44731684579412084], [0.13260155, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [-0.13260155, 0.5], [-0.25978993539242673, 0.44731684579412084], [-0.3535533905932738, 0.3535533905932738], [-0.44731684579412084, 0.25978993539242673], [-0.5, 0.13260155], [-0.5, 0.0], [-0.5, -0.13260155], [-0.44731684579412084, -0.25978993539242673], [-0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738], [-0.25978993539242673, -0.44731684579412084], [-0.13260155, -0.5], [0.0, -0.5]], ["M", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Z"]]], "edgecolors": ["#440154", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#35B778", "#FDE724", "#440154", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#30678D"], "edgewidths": [1.0], "offsets": "data01", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330713744", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#440154", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#30678D", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#35B778", "#FDE724", "#440154", "#FDE724", "#35B778", "#30678D"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data02", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330714960", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data03", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330715920", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data04", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415330717008", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}, {"paths": [[[[-0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, -0.5], [0.0, 0.5]], ["M", "L", "M", "L"]]], "edgecolors": ["#FF0000"], "edgewidths": [1.5], "offsets": "data05", "yindex": 1, "id": "el15021140415296729616", "pathtransforms": [[9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0, 9.820927516479827, 0.0, 0.0]], "pathcoordinates": "display", "offsetcoordinates": "data", "zorder": 1, "xindex": 0, "alphas": [null], "facecolors": ["#FF0000"]}], "xscale": "linear", "bbox": [0.125, 0.10999999999999999, 0.77500000000000002, 0.77000000000000002]}], "height": 480.0, "width": 640.0, "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"enabled": false, "button": true, "type": "zoom"}, {"enabled": false, "button": true, "type": "boxzoom"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:1"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330714960"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:2"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330715920"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:3"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330717008"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": ["UE:4"], "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415296729616"}, {"voffset": 10, "labels": null, "hoffset": 0, "location": "mouse", "type": "tooltip", "id": "el15021140415330713744"}], "data": {"data04": [[0.9272438562460922, 0.3299853259969276]], "data05": [[0.09099394357686544, -0.8983310538531637]], "data02": [[0.7580185107925308, 0.7591373404478057]], "data03": [[-0.8850288966385835, 1.4182636012752556]], "data01": [[-1.0, 1.5], [0.0, 1.5], [1.0, 1.5], [-1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5], [-1.0, -0.5], [0.0, -0.5], [1.0, -0.5], [-1.0, -1.5], [0.0, -1.5], [1.0, -1.5]]}, "id": "el15021140415424805456"});
            })
         });
}
</script>
```

In the console log I can see the javascript of the plot is received.However It is not populating on the HTML page.The entire application is designed in Django. Please Help.

Comment: please share how the response look like

Comment: Hi brk.I have added the response.

Comment: is this response  a html page?

Comment: It looks like it is javascript page.

Comment: did any of the following solutions worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

$('#plot').html(response); // if You want to Put Content which is already HTML Coded 
$('#plot').text(response); // if you just want to show that data to Front from Response

Answer (score 1):

if div id is "plot" :

```
$('#plot').html(reponse);
```